# Modification of the sql loader control file

Tags: oracle, import, sql-loader

I am working on a script which uses Oracle SQL *Loader to load data into a table. However, anywhere I search about the control file of an sql loader I am seeing only statements like:

```
"load data into table TABLE_NAME TRUNCATE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
Field1,
Field2,
Field3,
Field4)
'
```

Can I insert select statement in this control file ?

I suppose want to verify if `field3` in the incoming record has a certain value for which a record can be found in an existing table containing a similar field and if yes then it load the data and if no then it would send an output to a log file.

For example, for the incoming record, say p, I want to verify if the count of records for `(select * from table_k where field_demo = p.filed1)` is greater than zero or not. If it is greater than zero then it would insert the record into the table otherwise show an output message to the log file.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up a constraint on your p.filed1 column. Possibly you could use an insert trigger too.  But I forget if triggers are in effect when using sql loader.